# Reflection mapping with primitive types

Tags: java, jdbc, reflection, mapping

I needed a nestable bean rowmapper for JDBC, I used:

```
public class NestedRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<T> {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NestedRowMapper.class);

      private Class<T> mappedClass;

      public NestedRowMapper(Class<T> mappedClass) {
        this.mappedClass = mappedClass;
      }

      @Override
      public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        T mappedObject = BeanUtils.instantiate(this.mappedClass);
        BeanWrapper bw = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(mappedObject);

        bw.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true);

        ResultSetMetaData meta_data = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = meta_data.getColumnCount();

        for (int index = 1; index <= columnCount; index++) {

          String column=null;
          Object value=null;
          try {

            column = JdbcUtils.lookupColumnName(meta_data, index);
            value = JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(rs, index, Class.forName(meta_data.getColumnClassName(index)));

            bw.setPropertyValue(column, value);

          } catch (TypeMismatchException | NotWritablePropertyException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
              log.error("",column,value,bw.getClass().getSimpleName(),e);
          }
        }

        return mappedObject;
      }
    }
```

This well works, except when it found a primitive type, in that case BeanWrapper.setPropertyValue fails.

For example, if in my mapped bean there is a boolean (primitive) instead of Boolean (class) property, it fails. How can I correct it to let it map also primitive type property?

Comment: I have test, it works for primitive long. can you print you detail fail logs. for boolean, I think it is tinyint in database.

Comment: I got a static value with "select 1" query and it is not mapped to boolean true

Comment: Checkout my little library I wrote a while ago. I think it might be doing what you need. https://github.com/Jarcionek/Map-To-Object-Converter

Comment: @Tobia you write select 1 in your SQL, how can rs.getMetaData() can know it should be a boolean class or int or long?

Comment: jdbc get it as Long, but my bean has a boolean property. I cannot change it to Long because it is really a boolean for all other queries (tinyint(1)) but in this query I need a static 1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check the source code `org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper`, you need get class type from the java class define, not from the ResultSet metadata.

for example, replace your Class.forName(meta_data.getColumnClassName(index) with following method getClass(column)

```
private Class<?> getClass(String column) {
    PropertyDescriptor[] pds = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(this.mappedClass);
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
        if (pd.getName().equals(column)) {
            return pd.getPropertyType();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

it just an example, you need do cache/try catch like BeanPropertyRowMapper

Comment: Do you think it is enought to cache the field classes? Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a cached version with andy's solution, with fixed nested property lookup.

```
public class NestedRowMapper<T> implements RowMapper<T> {

      private Class<T> mappedClass;
      private Map<String, Class<?>> mappedFields=new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

      public NestedRowMapper(Class<T> mappedClass) {
        this.mappedClass = mappedClass;
      }

      @Override
      public T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {



        T mappedObject = BeanUtils.instantiate(this.mappedClass);
        BeanWrapper bw = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(mappedObject);

        bw.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true);

        ResultSetMetaData meta_data = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = meta_data.getColumnCount();

        for (int index = 1; index <= columnCount; index++) {

          try {

            String column = JdbcUtils.lookupColumnName(meta_data, index);
            Object value = JdbcUtils.getResultSetValue(rs, index, getColumnClass(column));
            bw.setPropertyValue(column, value);

          } catch (TypeMismatchException | NotWritablePropertyException e) {
          }
        }

        return mappedObject;
      }

    private Class<?> getColumnClass(String colName) {
        Class<?> out = mappedFields.get(colName);
        if (out == null){
            out=getBeanPropertyClass(colName,this.mappedClass);
            if(out != null)
                mappedFields.put(colName,out);
        }
        return out;
    }

    private Class<?> getBeanPropertyClass(String propName, Class<?> clazz) {
        int sep=propName.lastIndexOf(PropertyAccessor.NESTED_PROPERTY_SEPARATOR_CHAR);
        if(sep>0){
            Class<?> superclass=getBeanPropertyClass(propName.substring(0, sep),clazz);
            return getBeanPropertyClass(propName.substring(sep+1),superclass);
        }else{  
            PropertyDescriptor pd = BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(clazz, propName);
            if(pd!=null)
                return pd.getPropertyType();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can do all column cache in your NestedRowMapper constructor then BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors also only invoke once

Comment: MMh, my solution doesn't call getPropertyDescriptors() at once? I don't want to parse all columns because maybe I use a big Bean only for few fields.

Comment: for each column, you have call BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(this.mappedClass) once. I check the code of it, seems it using cache. so no problem for call multi times i think

Comment: @andy in your solution getClass("father.son") is returned always null. I fixed your solution and added a bean-property cache. I changed getPropertyDescriptors (many) with getPropertyDescriptor (single) because I know the property name. Thank you!